# Area of a plane region $g(x)=2x^2-x-1$ using rectangles to approximate the area

Tags: calculus, area

I'm doing this practice problem, where we are asked to "use left and right endpoints and the given number of rectangles to find two approximations of the area of the region between the graph of the function and the -axis over the given interval." They showed me how to do this with sums and I've been trying to do it with the endpoints but my answer is way off.

Here's the problem: $g(x)=2x^2-x-1, [2,5]$ with $6$ rectangles

I've tried to use right endpoint $1/2i$ and plug it into a sum like this:  $$\sum_{i = 1}^6 f\left(\frac{1}{2}i\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

This is the example in my book for plane area, but I keep getting $14.5$ as my answer and the book says I should be getting $55$. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm honestly thinking now my method is incorrect, but I'm not sure. Thanks

Edit: it works perfect between 5 and 10 just like you said. My question is how did you figure out that interval to use? I’m not sure if it’s obvious and this is a stupid question but my book didn’t elaborate about the upper and lower limits for this.

Comment: The formula you use does not fit the problem the first rectangle has f(2)*0,5, the second f(2,5)*0,5 and so on. Best you sketch the function and the 6 rectangles under it and than start to add the areas.

Comment: Not all of your right endpoints are in the interval.  The first right endpoint should be $2.5$ and the last should be $5$.  Therefore, your sum should be indexed from $i = 5$ to $10$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You have $6$ rectangles, so $ h = \dfrac{5-2}{6} = \dfrac{1}{2}$, then the summation (left endpoint) is

$S = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^5 f( 2 + i h ) h = h \sum_{i=0}^5 f(2 + i h) $

And this is equal to

$S = \frac{1}{2} \left( f(2) + f(2.5) + f(3) + f(3.5) + f(4) + f(4.5) \right)$

Since $f(x) = 2 x^2 - x -1 $ then the above evaluates to

$S = \dfrac{1}{2} (5 + 9 + 14 + 20 + 27 + 35) = 55 $

which is the answer given in the book.

Now, taking the right endpoint approximation, the summation is

$ \begin{equation}\begin{split} 
S &= \displaystyle h \sum_{i = 1}^6 f(2 + i h) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{2} (9 + 14 + 20 + 27 + 35 + 44) = 74.5\end{split}\end{equation} $

The actual integral is $\left[ \dfrac{2}{3} x^3 - \dfrac{1}{2} x^2 - x \right]_2^5 = 64.5 $

Comment: This is the left-endpoint approximation.

Comment: Thank you.  I've added the right-endpoint approximation.